# What would be an interesting good deed for a character

Tags: character-development

In my fictional story, I want my MC to discover that her father did something nice in the past, that he took the blame for something he hadn't done just to help someone.

Should be something that would harm his reputation, but not too much. Should not be something too heroic. Just some good deed.

I am having trouble figuring out what this guy did :-)

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE thedude, glad you found us.  Please check out our [tour] and [help].  We're different from other discussion sites out there because we're very focused on individual questions and we don't do critiques or idea generation.  So your question is off topic and will be closed.  Please do stick around and read and answer other questions and feel free to ask other questions to help you with your story.

Comment: As Cyn says, we cannot help you brainstorm. But here's a pointer: consider what would tie in to the themes and the setting of your story. Instead of trying to pick a random good deed, try to find one that would fit into the larger framework of your tale in some way.

Comment: He could [**save the cat**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blake_Snyder#Origin_of_the_title)…